# Using FocusLab MasterConfig Upload Preferences

Tags: file-uploads, focus-lab-master-config, config-overrides

I'm using FocusLab MasterConfig to set my upload preferences but strangely only the **name** of the Upload preference gets set by my code.  Here is the code in config.master.php

```
$resources_folder = 'resources';
$resources_path = $base_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $resources_folder;
$resources_url  = $base_url . '/' . $resources_folder;

$env_config['upload_preferences'] = array(
    7 => array(
        'name'        => 'Landing Page Banners',
        'server_path' => $resources_path . '/images/banners/landing/',
        'url'         => $images_url  . '/images/banners/landing/'
    ),
    8 => array(
        'name'        => 'Home Page Banners',
        'server_path' => $resources_path . '/images/banners/home/',
        'url'         => $images_url  . '/images/banners/home/'
    ));
```

Anyone know why the server_path and url (which are the important values) have no effect on the values shown in the CP?

Comment: maybe change your 
'url'         => $images_url  . '/images/banners/landing/'
to
'url'         => $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . '/images/banners/landing/'

Comment: That makes no difference.  The url is totally ignored.  This worked fine in the old ee version 2 configs.  N.B. I am using the ee3 version of masterConfig

Answer (score 0):

Did you test out an upload to your directories? It looks like only the name is read from the config variable, while the path / url in the CP will show what's in the database. But in use, reading and uploads to the file directories should use what you have in the Master Config settings -- overriding what's in the database.

Comment: I've tested my upload directories and they are set correctly.

Comment: So uploading a file works successfully in the ee control panel?

Comment: Yes it did.  I have 3 projects now with the same issue.  Beginning to believe that this is a bug.  Do you have this problem with any ee3 projects?